# Spring mvc error while binding date param

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, binding, jackson

I'm having a weird problem with a Spring MVC.
I have a Controller method that accepts 2 date parameters as request parameters `startDate` and `endDate`.
If I use a simple url with the 2 params like so :

```
http://localhost/myapp/videos?startDate=2013-05-10&endDate=2013-06-01.json
```

I get this error message :

```
[#|2013-05-27T17:39:01.711+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|38386 [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<Video> com.ufasoli.Videos.programs(com.ufasoli.filtering.SearchParams)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'searchParams' on field 'endDate': rejected value [2013-06-01.json]; codes [typeMismatch.searchParams.endDate,typeMismatch.endDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchParams.endDate,endDate]; arguments []; default message [endDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'endDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value '2013-06-01.json'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-06-01.json" is malformed at ".json"]
|#]
```

But as soon as I remove the `.json` like so :

```
http://localhost/myapp/videos?startDate=2013-05-10&endDate=2013-06-01
```

it all works fine...

This looks like a bug to me as the databinder should not take the url extension into account when binding the data to the controller or is this normal behavior?

Below is the controller method causing the problem :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/videos/", 
                 method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                 produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Videos> videos( SearchParams searchParams) {

        return videosRepository.videos(searchParams);
    }
```

Here is my SearchParams class :

```
public class SearchParams extends BaseSearchParams implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date endDate;

     //Setters/Getters
}
```

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2.1.RELEASE

Any insight?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the 'url extension' (if any) should be part of the path and belongs therefore before the query: `http://localhost/myapp/videos.json?startDate=2013-05-10&endDate=2013-06-01`.

Comment: Oh god i'm so stupid of course the extension id part of the url. I got it confused with path variables  Thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: I posted my comment as answer so you may mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the 'url extension' (if any) should be part of the path and belongs therefore before the query: `http://localhost/myapp/videos.json?startDate=2013-05-10&endDate=2013-06-01`.